# Why does sqlite3 still use __conform__?

Tags: python, sqlite, pep

I noticed that the `sqlite3`-library still uses the `__conform__`-method to adapt objects for storage in a database.

> Then you need to give your class a method `__conform__(self, protocol)` which must return the converted value.

[^ Python docs 12.6.6.2.1 ^](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html#letting-your-object-adapt-itself)

This seems to follow [PEP 246](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0246), which specifies the `__conform__`-method, but it has been rejected;

> I'm rejecting this PEP. Something much better is about to happen; it's too early to say exactly what, but it's not going to resemble the proposal in this PEP too closely so it's better to start a new PEP. GvR.

[^ Rejection notice of PEP 246 ^](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0246/#rejection-notice)

Now, how can it be that an official Python library implements [a standard](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0246) that has been defined in a suggestion that has explicitly been [**rejected**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0246/#rejection-notice)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**PEP 246** was a suggestion to implement a particular design pattern (testing if an incoming object adhered to a given protocol) using a particular name. The proposal, if accepted, would have added a new special method to the Python language (`__conform__`), as well as a new built-in function (`adapt`).

The PEP decision simply rejected standardization. It does not prohibit any Python package designers from creating and using such a pattern/naming convention internally in their code. This is analogous to the freedom the sqlite3 developers have in naming the `Cursor` method `fetchone()` rather than `fetchnext()`. They can name/design their package components however they like, within reason and utility.

**Update** - [according to Eric Snow](https://web.archive.org/web/20180715224620/https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-bugs-list/2012-June/171466.html), regarding the 'something much better' that was promised to be coming:

> At the time it referred to generic functions (a la PEP 3124: Overloading, Generic Functions, Interfaces, and Adaptation).  However, ultimately it was Abstract Base Classes (PEP 3119) that slid into this space.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, but I'd still like to know what "Something much better" in "Something much better is about to happen" was meant to mean, as I genuinely could not find it. (If you don't know it, please do say so.)

Comment: @ThomasE.Duursma I don't know either - and I agree, that comment by Guido is rather enigmatic :) I'll keep searching and update my answer if ever I find it.

Comment: @ThomasE.Duursma I told you I'd update the answer if I **ever** found the answer to your question. Two years later here we are :)

Comment: WOW! I just saw the little badge on my inbox. Thank you for the update! This is awesome.